# How to do URL rewriting in PHP and .htaccess files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url

In my PHP projects there are several types of URLs like:

- example.com/f/a/somefile.php?a=x
- example.com/f/a/somefile.php?a=x&b=y
- example.com/f/a/somefile.php?a=x&b=y&c=z
- example.com/f/somefile.php?a=x
- example.com/f/somefile.php?a=x&b=y
- example.com/f/somefile.php?a=x&b=y&c=z
- example.com/somefile.php?a=x
- example.com/somefile.php?a=x&b=y
- example.com/somefile.php?a=x&b=y&c=z

what are the best way to rewrite the URLs above,are there any ways to rewrite frienldy URLs rule that apply for all the URLs above?. TQ.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns and Replacements

The rule above allows you to redirect requests for a single URL, but the real power of mod_rewrite comes when you start to identify and rewrite groups of URLs based on patterns they contain.

Let's say you want to change all of your site URLs as described in the first pair of examples above. Your existing URLs look like this:

http://www.pets.com/show_a_product.php?product_id=7
And you want to change them to look like this:

http://www.pets.com/products/7/
Rather than write a rule for every single product ID, you of course would rather write one rule to manage all product IDs. Effectively you want to change URLs of this format:

http://www.pets.com/show_a_product.php?product_id={a number}
And you want to change them to look like this:

http://www.pets.com/products/{a number}/
In order to do so, you will need to use "regular expressions". These are patterns, defined in a specific format that the server can understand and handle appropriately. A typical pattern to identify a number would look like this:

[0-9]+
The square brackets contain a range of characters, and "0-9" indicates all the digits. The plus symbol indicates that the pattern will idenfiy one or more of whatever precedes the plus - so this pattern effectively means "one or more digits" - exactly what we're looking to find in our URL.

The entire "pattern" part of the rule is treated as a regular expression by default - you don't need to turn this on or activate it at all.

RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    show_a_product.php?product_id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
The first thing I hope you'll notice is that we've wrapped our pattern in brackets. This allows us to "back-reference" (refer back to) that section of the URL in the following "substitution" section. The "$1" in the substitution tells Apache to put whatever matched the earlier bracketed pattern into the URL at this point. You can have lots of backreferences, and they are numbered in the order they appear.

And so, this RewriteRule will now mean that Apache redirects all requests for domain.com/products/{number}/ to show_a_product.php?product_id={same number}.

Source: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Google Request: https://www.google.com/search?q=URL+mod-rewrite+htaccess